# Dúvida PDO SQL Injection

Tags: php, pdo, sql-injection

estou me aventurando um pouco com PDO, ainda no inicio, e tenho uma dúvida referente a uma query com SQL Injection, segue ela:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2, campo3) VALUES (:valor1, 
:valor2, :valor3)";

$db = new db();
$db = $db->connect();
$stat1 = $db->prepare($insert);
$stat1->execute([
  ":campo1" => $valor1,
  ":campo2" => $valor2,
  ":campo3" => $valor3
});
```

Isso estaria correto?
Está funcionando sem problemas, mas é seguro?

Muito obrigado galera!

Answer (score 0):

Está seguro sim, desde que você não concatene parâmetros com sua query($insert no caso) está tudo seguro